# Show page content during refresh action

Tags: angularjs

I have bootstrap tabs  with reports images which are generated by SSRS Server, saved in a folder on local server and updated every few minutes in the background. When user refreshes the page reports disappear. What I want to achieve is to show the reports during refresh action and update after refresh is finished without images disappearing.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: do you mean with refresh the page, that he is using the browser-refresh action? Like F5?

Comment: Yes, F5 of refresh invoked by location.reload()

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use *ng-src* directive, the reports disappear for a while, but after refresh is done, images from local server are loaded and updated after response from SSRS server.